# JQuery: Preventing a function from running, until another functions conditional has been met for "X" amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a script that when I "hover" a specific html element with a specific ID `id="HighlightCustomerName"`, that only after holding that "hover" for 2 or more second, a function will temporally apply a class `class="highlighted"` to HTML elements with another class `class="2Bhighlighted"`.

See Below, It doesn't work, but I think it illustrates what Im trying to do:

HTML:

```
<span id="HighlightCustomerName">John Doe</span>
<span class="2Bhighlighted">John Doe</span>
```

Jquery:

```
   $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
             $(".#HighlightCustomerName").hover(function () {
                  $(".2Bhighlighted").delay(2000).addclass("highlighting")
             });)
             if ( $(".2Bhighlighted").hasClass("highlighting"))
                  {
                       $(".2Bhighlighted").addClass("highlighted")
                  }
                  else{
                       $(".highlighted").removeclass("highlighted") 
                  }
       });
```

CSS:

```
highlighted {bakcground-color: yellow!important;}
```

Is this a good way to approach this?
Does anyone have a better way of doing this?
Im just about to

Comment: Use setTimeout() and clearTimeout()?

Comment: `if ( $(".2Bhighlighted").hasClass("highlighting"))` This condition is pointless. Just `$(".highlighted").removeclass("highlighted")` - if it doesn't have the class it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css3 transitions and avoid jquery altogether:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Answer</title>
    <script>
        function changeStyle(className, colorName) {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
            element[0].style.transition = "background 1.0s linear 2.0s";
            element[0].style.background = colorName;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="HighlightCustomerName"
          onmouseover="changeStyle('2Bhighlighted','yellow');"
          onmouseout="changeStyle('2Bhighlighted','white');">John Doe</span>
    <span class="2Bhighlighted">John Doe</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var highlightTimeout;
$("#HighlightCustomerName").hover(function () {
    highlightTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
        $(".2Bhighlighted").addclass("highlighting");
    }, 2000);
}, function(){
   $(".highlighted").removeclass("highlighted"); // no point checking, just remove it
   clearTimeout(highlightTimeout); // this prevents it from happening
});
```

Also note your selector `.#HighlightCustomerName` was wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $('#hoverMe');

hoverChange(element, function() {
    element.addClass('red');
});

function hoverChange(element, fn) {

    var timer = null;

    element.mouseenter(function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            fn();
        }, 2000)
    });

    element.mouseout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    });

}
```

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GwADf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set and clear a timer to make this work:

- When you start hover, set a timer for 2 seconds.
- When you stop hovering, clear any timer that is currently running.
- If 2 seconds passes without stop hovering, the timer will fire
- You can then add the temporary class.
- If you want to remove the temporary class after some period of time, do another `setTimeout()` for removing the temporary class

Here's the code with some explanatory comments:

```
var timer;
$("#HighlightCustomerName").hover(function () {
    // if a timer was already running, clear it so we never have multiple ones
    clearTimeout(timer);
    // set a timer for 2 seconds
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // we've been hovering for 2 seconds
        // add your class here
        $(".2Bhighlighted").addClass("highlighting");
        // then remove the class 5 seconds later
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".2Bhighlighted").removeClass("highlighting");
        }, 5000);
    }, 2000);
}, function() {
    // if we stop hovering, clear the timer
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Your code also had a number of other errors:

1. You had a selector `".#HighlightCustomerName"` which does not look right.  You are either querying for a class with a `.` or an ID with `#`, but not both.
2. Your capitalization of `addClass()` and `removeClass()` is not correct.